# Formatting issue with getline()

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read some data out of a text file. One of the data names is `Chamber temperature [°C]`. I read the file with the command: `getline(myfile, tab, '\t');` out.

The problem is that the degree sign is formatted into `"Chamber temperature [�C]"`.

How can I prevent c++ from deformatting the degree sign?

P.S. : In the text file the sign is formatted correctly

Code:

```
 //just create a txt file on your desktop which only stores "Chamber Temperature [°C]
 myfile.open("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.txt");  
 string tab = "";
 getline(myfile, tab, '\t');
 cout << tab << endl;
```

When you have the same setting as i described below you should have the same problem, well it is not a Problem just a language difference. UTF-8 just cant interpret the signs as ANSI.

There are solutions in which I can look for the substring and then replace the format as I wish, but I would like to have a foolproof and safe way to use this code in any case. So I'm looking for a conversion between these 2 languages.

---

Additional Information about my environment:

I use eclipse with a MinGW compiler and the accent c++11. I use default text file encoding UTF-8 and the new Text file delimiter UNIX.
I opened the file in notepad++ and it gives me the estimation of the file format "ANSI". 
I use a simple `ifstream` to read the data into a 3D vector (first dimension: file; second dimension: row data; third dimension:columns). I use the `getline` to read each sequence delimited by a tab into a variable ... and in the end into my matrix.

Now after I have stored the data into my matrix I so some data searching and here comes my problem. Because the file is formatted in ANSI I cant compare the string `Chamber Temperature [°C]` with the stored data, since it will never find it.

I need to convert the text file into UTF-8 format and then store it into my 3D matrix. Is this possible? I new into coding, so could you please provide me with an example code or pseudo code?

Comment: Determine the encoding of the file, and imbue the appropriate locale into the `std::ifstream`.

Comment: Which character code are you using? Is there any reason why you don't want to post  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also information about your environment (compiler, OS, terminal software, etc.) may be useful.

Comment: Hey Sam, my file is encoded in ANSI format. Could you give me an example how continue to get the right format, in my case ascii?

Comment: Or i think i need UTF-8 format for the database that i create with c++

Comment: Well here is more information about my environment. I use eclipse with a MinGW compiler and the accent c++11. I use default text file encoding UTF-8 and the new Text file delimiter UNIX.

Comment: If you are willing to convert your text file, you can just use a text editor like Notepad++, or even your Eclipse might be able to do it. In Notepad++ there is a menu "encoding" with convert options, other editors allow to set the encoding in the "Save as" dialog.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].